# FabricJS Performance issue using object:moving

Tags: javascript, canvas, fabricjs

my canvas get really slow whenever I use `object:moving` for a long period of time, I use it to show guide lines whenever an user centers an object to the middle of the canva.

You can see by yourself on JSFiddle by moving a shape for 10-20 sec, you'll see that everything goes slow after moving it too much, it becomes really hard to work with : https://jsfiddle.net/ohu3zg57/1/

Here is the JS code I'd like to improve so this issue doesn't happen :

```
// Horizontal Snap Line
var snapZone = 10;
canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  var objectMiddle = options.target.left + options.target.getWidth() / 2;
  if (objectMiddle > canvas.width / 2 - snapZone && objectMiddle < canvas.width / 2 + snapZone) {
    options.target.set({
      left: canvas.width / 2 - options.target.getWidth() / 2
    }).setCoords();
   }
});

canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
  var objectMiddle = options.target.left + options.target.getWidth() / 2;
  if (objectMiddle > canvas.width / 2 - snapZone && objectMiddle < canvas.width / 2 + snapZone) {
    var line1 = new fabric.Line([
      canvas.width / 2, 0,
      canvas.width / 2, canvas.width
    ], {
      strokeDashArray: [6, 6],
      stroke: '#ccc',
      opacity: 1
    });
    line1.selectable = false;
    line1.evented = false;
    line1.hasControls = false;
    line1.hasBorders = false;
    canvas.add(line1);
  }

    if (objectMiddle == canvas.width / 2) {
    canvas.on('mouse:up', function(options) {
        line1.setOpacity('0');
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
    canvas.on('object:moving', function(options) {
        line1.setOpacity('0');
        canvas.renderAll();
    });
    }
});
```

As you can see I'm using `object:moving` 2x and also `mouse:up` 1x, rendering everything makes it really slow and complicated to work, and doing that for each lines add another complexity.

What is the best way to avoid messing performance like I did and keep a fast canvas where this feature still work without any trouble ?

Comment: I'm not seeing your performance problems, but there is room for improvement in the code.  What browser(s) are you seeing the performance problems in?

Comment: @TimHarker Mostly on Firefox, I reproduced the same issue with Chrome but it took a lot more time to trigger it. At the begining it's easy to move but if you trigger the lines while moving a shape for too long then any manipulation becomes not smooth and slow.

Comment: Hi, It' s seems that I have the same problem. It looks like increasing zoom triggers low perfromance even faster. Did you manage to solve it?

Comment: @bartosz.baczek actually I've changed to hand made javascript app, since it's an issue to work on canvas, you can copy it on designbold or canvas they also avoid 'canvas'.

Comment: This seems to be broken by 2.0.0. Reverting to 1.7.20 fixes this for me.